# Proper way to illuminate a 2D surface in 3D space?

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit

**EDIT:** I've solved the issue below the tilde line -- the missing chunks -- by fixing an elementary error in my for-loop dealing with calculating face normals. I now have a new problem though: strange, unwanted shadows on the surface itself. Some areas appear darker than others... See the next picture for the current issue.

I have an omni light added to my scene's root node as well as a directional light added in the same manner. For some reason I can't seem to light the underbelly of the surface otherwise. Notice the strange shadow on the inside of the concave surface (it's more pronounced when I remove the subdivision effect as I have done here) -->

[image]

Here is the surface from above -- notice how some areas seem strangely darker.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This is a concave surface.

[image]

I have these smooth, curved planes in 3D space. Right now, they look rather cartoonish -- I would like to utilize some form of lighting to make them look more "3D-ish."

I have tried various combinations of ambient lighting, omni lighting, and default lighting, but nothing seems to work right. I get something quite strange when I apply something like a basic omni light --

[image]

Here is another look at a better angle using omni lighting. Looks like someone took a bite out of it --

[image]

Am I overlooking a specific type of light or lighting strategy?

I'd like to avoid used baked lighting, because the scene is rather simple. Thanks.

I'll outline my steps for the bold.

1: I specify the vertices for each of the four faces of a pyramid-like shape. Like this (apologies for my lack of artistic ability) -->

[image]

2: I specify the indices for the face, i.e., [0,1,2, 0,2,3, etc.]

3. I create a dictionary mapping each vertex to the sum of that vertex's adjacent, normalized face normals.
4. I append each of these summed up normalized per-vertex normals to a vector.
5. I combine the vertices, indices, and vector of normals to create an SCN Geometry.
6. To get the rounded look, I increase the subdivision count.
7. Pray that it works.

I'm new to the 3D world, so I could be way out in left field and not even know it.

Comment: maybe you could attach screenshots of what you have now, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Parallax mapping seems like the most obvious solution to me, but it won't be useful if they're supposed to be smooth.

Comment: imagine a pringle -- you can tell it's smooth and curved. that's what I'd like. what I have right now is more like a a black pringle that has no shading, curves, etc. And yep, @Jessy, these surfaces must be smooth.

Comment: Wow! My first guess is that you have a set of vertexes for each side, but SOME of them they're shared at the edge. Have you taken this into Unity or something as a sanity check?

Comment: Where are you lights positioned relative to the objects you're trying to light up? It seems the shadows being cast are much longer than they should be, generally something caused by lights being too oblique to the subject. Great for portraits, not so good for this.

Comment: you should probably double-check your surface normals. My guess is that the lighting is wrong because the normals are incorrect.

Comment: Jessy, what do you mean "shared at the edge?" Don't all triangles share edges/why would that be a problem? Confused, the shape looks plain weird regardless of where I place the omni light

Comment: @Jessy, check the edit if you have a chance. I'm not sure whether the new issue could be a manifestation of what you initially suggested. At least I've got a continuous smooth surface now...

Comment: That only shows one side. I was talking about the edge of the shape, not an edge of a triangle that makes up a side.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a reasonable result with minimal effort and the least possible need to understand 3D lighting.

Open the Fox game example/sample from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Fox/Introduction/Intro.html

Delete everything from the level.scn Scene Graph other than Lights, Camera and the Mountain.

And then add your geometry object to a node at the bottom, where I have the sphere highlighted at the bottom of the Scene Graph....

[image: Scene Graph of level.scn in Apple's Fox SNK sample]

Now the material needs a bit of work, to make it useful.

Select the Mountain by clicking on it in the View, and goto the material editor and make it look like this, just keep checking against this image until yours matches the few (weird) changes I've made. And trust me this will work out fine:

[image: Material Settings]

When you want to get that lovely red you have, you simply change this property: DIFFUSE : It's right at the top of the Material settings.

Now you have a material and lighting setup that gives a reasonable approximation of curvature in a 3D space.

Applying this material to your object is a little weird, and unintuitive, you go here, and click on the add button, and pick the material with the same name as the one in the above image, that’s on the mountain.

[image: Apply Material to another object:]

You can improve this by adding two more lights in what’s known as a “3 point lighting setup”, google this phrase to see it explained.

Further, you can add off screen (out of camera) placards, usually white, to manage key reflections to further assist in users getting a feel for what’s being presented.

Comment: Thanks. That'd be great if I were starting from scratch. However, the surfaces that I'm having trouble with must interact with a scene graph, which otherwise looks/works fine, that is already in place.

Comment: This will give you a scene you can see shows 3D curvature well. From it you can replicate the lighting and other settings within it until you get what you need.

Comment: Otherwise you're going to need to come to terms with understanding 3D lighting ideas in a much more thorough manner, which takes some time, and isn't wholesale applicable to Scene Kit because it's missing much of what would be in a more fully capable 3D scene maker.

Comment: As I say at the start, this is the fastest way to get to a result that's maybe acceptable.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure your way is great if you're building an entire 3D scene. I've hacked my way to something acceptable at this point. All that's messed up is the "edit" that I mention at the top of the question now -- some unfortunate shadows. That seems like it should be a relatively easy fix at this point, as opposed to building the entire scene over again in xcode's game-building environment.

Comment: In fewer words -- I have all the 3d shapes I need at this point. The only issue is some peculiar shadowing on the surfaces whose existence I can't explain

Comment: And can you give me the information about your lighting setup vs the positions of your objects in 3D?

Comment: Three key points: Material, Reflection and Lighting determine how things look in 3D. Reflection is the one that's most important (after the other two) when it comes to complex curvatures as it's how we're accustomed to mentally perceiving the complex surfaces of cars, hence my suggestion of a pseudo metallic look. Lighting needs to be mostly high up, so as to ensure shadows go down, off the edges of the objects. And then materials and lighting setups control how the shadows influence perception of light and dark on the objects. It is a nightmare the first few times because there's no "normal".